# String Swap-case one-liners (6 ways)

Tags: c#, strings, comparative-review

I did this small project where there are six one-liner anonymous methods that can swap case of a given string of any length. For example "heLLo, woRLd" ==> "HEllO, WOrlD". I used this string as the example to demonstrate how each of the function works. This string "heLLo, woRLd" can simply be replaced with Console.ReadLine() to get user anticipated inputs. I understand one-liners are not readable and maybe not considered good practice, and used variable names are not proper as well. This whole project was for fun. I believe that way I can learn more. My expectation is that someone can tell me if there are more ways to do this case-swapping (of course, has to be one-liner)?. I think I used 3 (kinda) algorithms to do the swapping. Moreover, all of the one-liners are void functions and all the succeeding functions are shorter than the preceding ones.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class x
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // one-liner string swapcase
        (new Action<string>(delegate (string x) { foreach (char i in x) { char b = i; b^= char.IsLetter(b) ? (char)32 : (char)0; Console.Write(b); } }))("heLLo, woRLd");

        Console.WriteLine();

        //one-liner string swapcase2
        (new Action<string>(delegate (string x) { foreach (char i in x) { Console.Write(char.IsUpper(i) ? char.ToLower(i) : char.ToUpper(i)); } }))("heLLo, woRLd");

        Console.WriteLine();

        // one-liner string swapcase3
        ((Action<string>)(delegate (string x) { foreach (char i in x) { Console.Write(char.IsUpper(i) ? char.ToLower(i) : char.ToUpper(i)); } }))("heLLo, woRLd");

        Console.WriteLine();

        //one-liner string swapcase4
        ((Action<string>)((x) => { foreach (char i in x) { Console.Write(char.IsUpper(i) ? char.ToLower(i) : char.ToUpper(i)); } }))("heLLo, woRLd");

        Console.WriteLine();

        //one-liner string swapcase5
        "heLLo, woRLd".ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write(char.IsUpper(i) ? char.ToLower(i) : char.ToUpper(i)));

        Console.WriteLine();
        //one-liner string swapcase6
        "heLLo, woRLd".ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write(i^= char.IsLetter(i) ? (char)(1 << 5) : (char)0));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also loop with `foreach (var c in "heLLo, woRLd") {...}`.

Comment: Excluding your last 2 examples, all the rest are not 1 liners, if you consider them 1 line, then you might as well call your entire file 1 liner. Also I wouldn't call a small change of anonymous methods vs lambda, a different way of doing it.

Comment: @Denis could u care to explain why they r not one-liners? From taking input to printing output was done in a single line. If u don’t consider lambda a way of doing one-liner than plz come up with a better explanation.

Answer (score 9):

I find your code amusing but since this is not Code Golf but Code Review I'll review it from *our* perspective this is, as clean-code first.

Even if you try to write compact code you should not use *magic* exressions and sacrifice readability. Instead encapsulate them in (local) function or use proper constants. You also should not use unrelated variable names like here `i` for `char` where `c` would be more appropriate. Alternatively you can also use the `Aggregate` to loop over the string and collect the results in a `StringBuilder`. The `(char)0` can be replaced with the much prettier `default`.

```
const char caseOffset = (char)(1 << 5);

char SwapCase(char c) => c ^= (char.IsLetter(c) ? caseOffset : default);

var result = 
    "heLLo, woRLd"
        .Aggregate(
            new StringBuilder(), 
            (b, c) => b.Append(SwapCase(c))
        ).ToString();
```

One more option would be to use `Select` and `new string` and feed it with the new result.

```
var result = new string("heLLo, woRLd".Select(SwapCase).ToArray())
```

The advantage of `Select` is that you don't need the `=>` lambda anymore.

Comment: Again, our definitions of code-golf will have to differ! You can have a +1 if you add a brief comment to this fine answer about Unicode; there isn't much more I'd say that would warrant a full answer ;)

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned before that it was for fun. So, I didn’t consider readability. Your solutions are interesting, but I was expecting to have one-liners (from taking input to printing output in one line. But I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @VisualMelon I quess I'm not going to earn that +1 :P as I have no idea how to deal with unicode exactly (right now) let's wait for Adrianno Repetti - he's the unicode expert - I know that it won't work for every language and to be honest... I naively assumed the english alphabet. Would I have to work with other languages I'd probably go with `ToUpper/Lower`.

Comment: @t3chb0t oh, well have it anyway then! I'll await Adrianno Repetti to tell us how it should be done properly instead of making something up :P

Comment: `SwapCase` should be an extension method on `char` and should use `IsUpper`, `ToUpper`, and `ToLower` to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to thank @t3chb0t for giving such concrete feedback; thanks to this person I was able to have more ways to do the swapping of this above mentioned string. I am posting this as an answer since none else contributed any actual one-liners to my question.

```
//one-liner string swapcase7 ***idea from @t3chb0t***
Console.WriteLine(new string("heLLo, woRLd".Select(i => i^= char.IsLetter(i) ? (char)(1 << 5) : default).ToArray()));

//one-liner string swapcase8 ***idea from @t3chb0t***    
Console.WriteLine("heLLo, woRLd".Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (b, o) => b.Append(((Func<char, char>)((a) => { a ^= char.IsLetter(a) ? (char)(1 << 5) : default; return a; }))(o))).ToString());

//one-liner string swapcase9 ***my own understanding of LINQ***
Console.WriteLine(new string((from i in "heLLo, woRLd" select ((Func<char, char>)((a) => { a ^= char.IsLetter(a) ? (char)(1 << 5) : default; return a; }))(i)).ToArray()));
```

Comment: Since OP apparently doesn't need a newline in the one-liner: `Console.Write` accepts a `char[]`, so you save the `Line` and don't need the `new string(char[])`